# Error pd.pivot "MultiIndex.name must be a hashable type"

Tags: python, pandas

I´m trying to apply to my pandas dataframe something similar to R's tidyr::spread . I saw in some places people using pd.pivot but so far I had no success.

So in this example I have the following dataframe DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'action_id' : [1,2,1,4,5],
               'name': ['jess', 'alex', 'jess', 'cath', 'mary'],
              'address': ['house', 'house', 'park', 'park', 'park'],
               'date': [ '01/01', '02/01', '03/01', '04/01', '05/01']})
```

How does it look like:

[image]

Ok, so what I want is a multi-index pivot table having 'action_id' and 'name' as index, "spread" the address column and fill it with the 'date' column. So my df would look like this:

[image]

What I tryed to do was:

```
df.pivot(index = ['action_id', 'name'], columns = 'address', values = 'date')
```

And I got the error *TypeError: MultiIndex.name must be a hashable type*

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to mention the index in `pd.pivot`

This will work

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'action_id' : [1,2,1,4,5],
               'name': ['jess', 'alex', 'jess', 'cath', 'mary'],
              'address': ['house', 'house', 'park', 'park', 'park'],
               'date': [ '01/01', '02/01', '03/01', '04/01', '05/01']})

df = pd.concat([df, pd.pivot(data=df, index=None, columns='address', values='date')], axis=1) \
            .reset_index(drop=True).drop(['address','date'], axis=1)
print(df)

   action_id  name  house   park
0          1  jess  01/01    NaN
1          2  alex  02/01    NaN
2          1  jess    NaN  03/01
3          4  cath    NaN  04/01
4          5  mary    NaN  05/01
```

And to arrive at what you want, you need to do a groupby

```
df = df.groupby(['action_id','name']).agg({'house':'first','park':'first'}).reset_index()
print(df)
   action_id  name  house   park
0          1  jess  01/01  03/01
1          2  alex  02/01    NaN
2          4  cath    NaN  04/01
3          5  mary    NaN  05/01
```

Dont forget to accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: I understand what you did, but is it there a way to do that only with one function?

Comment: I am afraid not.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['action_id','name','address']).date.unstack().reset_index()
df2.columns.name = None
```